# Using LocalStorage only upon closing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a web app that keeps track of given values even when the user exits their browser.  I understand that I can use localStorage to do this, but trying to implement this is kind of weird.  One of the values I want to save is a number value that is a counter essentially, and will be going up to the millions and billions.  It doesn't make sense for me to continually store that number over and over and over again.  In my mind the easiest way to go about this is just storing the values if the user exits the page.  However, I'm not exactly sure if this is possible.  Is there a more intuitive way to do what I am trying to do or is it best to just continuously store the value as it increases?

Comment: [WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can store the value once when user is exiting the browser tab and that would be better instead of regularly updating the value.
2. If you want to store value on before browser tab close, you can use below code:

**window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {})**

So as soon as user close the tab, it will get hit in the callback and you can store the value in localStorage in that callback.

o